# Run a ping command on list of servers and output to a file

Tags: ssh, scripting, ping

I have a file `servers.txt` on a different server, with list of servers:

```
server1.mydomain.com
server2.mydomain.com
server3.mydomain.com
```

I want to first download this txt file, ping these servers and output the ping result into a file. And I want to do this on an infinite loop every x seconds.

I have a VPS login and so far I have figured out to connect to the VPS using a program called `putty.exe`.

How should I approach this? I would imagine I should write a script and set the server to run it each x seconds or use a while loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "on a different server"?  If you're using `putty` then you're starting from an MS Windows machine to which you're logging into a Linux VPS (let's call it `host1`).  Is the `servers.txt` file on `host1` or on another host (let's call it `host2`)?  The solution for both cases is not difficult but is very different.

Comment: @grochmal sorry for the confusion. It is on `host2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I believe I understand your question now.

### On host1

Let us assume that you have `host1` to which you connect with `ssh` via `putty`, on this host you shall install `screen` or `tmux` (from the package manager, they shall be there).  I suggest `screen` since it is a little easier for a beginner.

Also, you need to be able to login to `host2` from `host1` therefore you need to setup a `ssh key` which will allow for login without a password.  To perform this you need to run:

```
ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/host1tohost2
```

It will ask for a passphrase, to perform the script automatically (without the need for manual input of a passphrase) you shall set it to an empty passphrase.  **Keep host1 safe!  Thanks to this key anyone in control of `host1` also gains control of `host2` (to the extent the user permissions allow).**

That command will generate the following files:

```
~/.ssh/host1tohost2
~/.ssh/host1tohost2.pub
```

You shall copy `~/.ssh/host1tohost2.pub` to `host2`:

```
scp ~/.ssh/host1tohost2.pub me@host2:~
```

### On host2

Create `~/.ssh` in host2 and move `host1tohost2.pub` there, then create a file called `authorized_keys` in that directory:

```
mkdir -f ~/.ssh
mv ~/host1tohost2.pub ~/.ssh
cd ~/.ssh
cat host1tohost2.pub >> authorized_keys
```

This allows for login from `host1` to `host2` without an interactive password prompt.

*Next,*

Let us assume that the file `servers.txt` is at `/home/me/myservers/servers.txt` on `host2`.  This assumption is needed since we will be using this `path` in a script at `host1`.

### Back to host1

The infinite loop script you need is:

```
#!/bin/sh

X_SECONDS=6
LOGFILE=~/mypings.log

while ((1)); do
    # >$LOGFILE  # clear log file (see comments)
    ssh -i ~/.ssh/host1tohost2 me@host2 'cat /home/me/myservers/servers.txt' |
    while read x; do
        echo "ping to $x"
        ping -c1 $x >> $LOGFILE
    done
    sleep $X_SECONDS
done
```

Let's assume that this script is saved to a file called `pingservers.sh`. But do not run it yet, since it will stop once you close `putty`.  Now `screen` comes into the scene (you installed it, right?).  Run:

```
screen
```

And apparently nothing changes.  You're now in a `shell` that is being accessed through a `socket` in `/var/run`, this shell will not close once if you `detach` from it and then close `putty` (actually if you just close `putty` the OS will figure things out and not close the shell anyway, but let's do a proper `detach` for educational reasons).  Before detaching it is time to run:

```
./pingservers.sh
```

It will run forever, and keep `echo`ing a couple of messages while writing to the log file.

To detach from `screen` you need to enter `Ctrl+A D` (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, press <kbd>A</kbd>, release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>D</kbd>).  And you're back in the original `shell` you logged in with `putty`, you can now close `putty` and have a coffee.

Once you login back into `host1` the file `~/mypings.log` shall be updated with more and more pings (no need to run `screen` again).  To check the file being updated in real-time you can use:

```
tail -f ~/mypings.log
```

---

The [arch linux wiki has much more useful info about ssh-keygen and ssh keys in general](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_keys), and the same is true about [gnu screen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen).  These two articles are excellent source of information for both programs.

Comment: OK. As far as I can understand this pretty much answers everything. But I want the file to just have 1 set of pings (not just appending to the existing file). One solution would be to delete the file before the `while` loop. Is there a better solution? Also, I assume that the `servers.txt` is not publicly accessible but it is in the `host1` server using this method, correct?

Comment: I added a small edit (but left it commented it out in case other people find this question/answer through google), instead of deleting the file it is more elegant to overwrite it with an empty stream, i.e. `>file` (this is also faster than recreating the file).  I'm a little confused about the second part of your comment, but i'll try to answer it:  `servers.txt` is copied as a stream to the script at `host1`, it is copied each time so when it gets updated on `host2` the script picks it.  The communication happens over `ssh` therefore it is authenticated and encrypted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it and hopefully I can do everything without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `cat servers.txt` ; do ping -c1 $i 2>&1 | tee >> ping-output.txt; done
```

This executes a ping for each line in the file (using i as the variable that stores the value and referencing the variable with $i) and redirects all output into the [output] file. The 2>&1 part captures the stdout (ping results) and the stderr (no ping because no host error) into a file using the tee command.

Comment: To make the answer more complete, you should wrap it in another infinite loop as requested.  Note that I see no benefit for using `tee` here as the ping command can be properly redirected on its own.

Comment: On my system, I created the example servers.txt file. When I ran the above command without the `| tee` part and it did not capture the message from the system about it being unresolvable which might be helpful. 
`ping: unknown host server1.mydomain.com`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get the loop and the syntax (I'm a programmer) but I'm having a little trouble understanding one thing. When I run this command, will I need to keep the putty open or will it run infinitely? (assuming I wrap this with another loop). I want it to run infinitely without my interaction.

Comment: while [ 1 ] ; do for i in `cat servers.txt` ; do ping -c1 $i 2>&1 | tee >> ping-output.txt; done ; done  <-- will run indefinitely. But it will fill up the hard drive eventually. And doesn't show output. So, if you run screen, you can open up a new session and tail -f the output file. ¯\(°_o)/¯ 
First real thought was install nagios with email notifications, but that's quite a leap. 
Check out fping: http://www.tecmint.com/install-fping-icmp-program-on-rhel-centos-6-5-4/

Comment: watch nmap -sn server1.mydomain.com server2.mydomain.com server3.mydomain.com

Will show results of the ping scan every 2 seconds.